# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to create a program that takes int t and String s from the user. String s will be split at the spaces and put into a String[] Strings. When t=1, the main method prints Strings, reverses its elements using recursion in method reverse that takes two ints (the indices of the ends) and a String array, then print the reversed String array. The code below compiled with no problems, but I got an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error right when I hit enter inputting 1 for t. The error references lines 11 and 34, but I'm scratching my head because I can't see anything wrong.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Recursion
    {
        public static String[] reverse(int m, int n, String[] str)
        {
            String[] p = new String[str.length];
            if (m == n) return str;
            else if (m > n) return str;
            else
            {
                str[m] = p[n];
                str[n] = p[m];
                return reverse(m+1, n-1, str);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("t = ");
            int t = enter.nextInt();
            System.out.print("s = ");
            String str = enter.nextLine();

            String[] Strings = str.split(" ");
            int k = Strings.length;

            if (t == 1)
            {
                for (String s : Strings)
                    System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println("The reversal is");
                reverse(k-k, k, Strings);
                for (String s : Strings)
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by changing `reverse(k-k, k, Strings);` to `reverse(0, Strings.length - 1, Strings);`

Answer (score 0):

Array in java start from 0 to length -1

see [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details.

so passing k will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` use below code

```
reverse(0, k-1, Strings);
```

Comment: Thank you.This simple blunder now makes ashamed to be enrolled in a programming course. /s

Comment: @ColeBalajadia don't be, we all do simple mistake all the times :P